# Error occurred during camel start because of circular dependency

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

On placing a bundle (using `camel`) on Karaf I am seeing the below exception. The below exception comes only when the bundle is started. After that everything works fine. The exeception does not seem to effect our functionality. The issue is coming on both `camel 2.16.1` (deployed on `servicemix 6.1.0`) and `camel 2.16.3` (deployed on `servicemix 7.0.0M2`).

My `blueprint` is split into three files. A simplified version of them are shown below:-

1. `blueprint.xml` placed [here](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/42294561b9da22ce2281e6a9f3b22a34).
2. `productBeans.xml` placed [here](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/5c406f597f8b7248369b206ed1f93842).
3. `camelContext.xml` placed [here](https://gist.github.com/debraj-manna/4210653d661beaee6beb87900c4f4911).

Can some please let me know why is this exception coming during bundle start? It appears from the below stack-trace that it is because of some circular dependency. How can I get around this?

```
2016-07-04 11:29:37,497 | ERROR | mix-6.1.0/deploy | BlueprintCamelContext            | 143 - org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint - 2.16.1 | {{bundle.id,143}{bundle.name,org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint}{bundle.version,2.16.1}} | Error occurred during starting Camel: CamelContext(camel-1) due Failed to create route orchestrator-service-route at: >>> process[ref:jsonRPCProcessor] <<< in route: Route(orchestrator-service-route)[[From[jetty:http://0.0.0.0... because of Cannot lookup: jsonRPCProcessor from registry: org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry@7b081b97 with expected type: interface org.apache.camel.Processor due: [BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='.camelBlueprint.bean.factory.myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='camel-1'], BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate']]
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route orchestrator-service-route at: >>> process[ref:jsonRPCProcessor] <<< in route: Route(orchestrator-service-route)[[From[jetty:http://0.0.0.0... because of Cannot lookup: jsonRPCProcessor from registry: org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry@7b081b97 with expected type: interface org.apache.camel.Processor due: [BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='.camelBlueprint.bean.factory.myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='camel-1'], BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate']]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:947)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3258)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2981)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2812)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2831)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2777)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.start(BlueprintCamelContext.java:180)[143:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.1]
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.maybeStart(BlueprintCamelContext.java:212)[143:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.1]
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.serviceChanged(BlueprintCamelContext.java:150)[143:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:932)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:793)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4419)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3423)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintCamelContext.init(BlueprintCamelContext.java:100)[143:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.16.1]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:956)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:247)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:145)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:754)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.CamelProducerTemplateFactoryBean.getCamelContextWithId(CamelProducerTemplateFactoryBean.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractCamelFactoryBean.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_77]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:299)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:956)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:280)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:931)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:905)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:886)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:247)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:183)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:682)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:377)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:294)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:263)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:253)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[9:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.1]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1103)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:695)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:483)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4403)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2092)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.2.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.startBundle(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:518)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeatures(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:476)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.FeaturesServiceImpl.installFeature(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:417)[20:org.apache.karaf.features.core:3.0.5]
    at Proxy1be55f4b_f63a_43b3_883f_77a48747d768.installFeature(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxy1fa9f34f_3928_4828_8542_9d785df163bd.installFeature(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.installFeatures(KarServiceImpl.java:215)[160:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.install(KarServiceImpl.java:96)[160:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.karaf.kar.internal.KarServiceImpl.install(KarServiceImpl.java:84)[160:org.apache.karaf.kar.core:3.0.5]
    at Proxya6f8b1d5_e9a2_4e1b_a105_1552c365b9de.install(Unknown Source)[:]
    at Proxye3575645_14c4_4cf9_8d71_16cd6e82b1a0.install(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar.KarArtifactInstaller.install(KarArtifactInstaller.java:50)[162:org.apache.karaf.deployer.kar:3.0.5]
    at Proxy6b7a1495_9239_4ff3_b9ed_1fd58a17750b.install(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:931)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.install(DirectoryWatcher.java:865)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:482)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[7:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: Cannot lookup: jsonRPCProcessor from registry: org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry@7b081b97 with expected type: interface org.apache.camel.Processor due: [BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='.camelBlueprint.bean.factory.myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='camel-1'], BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate']]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(CompositeRegistry.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookup(CamelContextHelper.java:137)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:157)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.mandatoryLookup(DefaultRouteContext.java:151)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessDefinition.java:95)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
    ... 105 more
Caused by: org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.CircularDependencyException: [BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='.camelBlueprint.bean.factory.myTemplate'], BeanRecipe[name='camel-1'], BeanRecipe[name='myTemplate']]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.push(BlueprintRepository.java:343)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:71)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:247)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:145)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:754)[15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.4]
    at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(BlueprintContainerRegistry.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(CompositeRegistry.java:56)
    ... 114 more
```

**EDIT** - It seems the error is because the `jsonRPCProcessor` is using `myTemplate` as shown below:-

```
<bean id="jsonRPCProcessor"     class="com.j1.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.JSONRPCProcessor">
        <argument ref="myTemplate" />
        <argument>
            <map>           
                <!-- Product End Points -->
                <entry key="Product.createProducts" value-ref="createProductsWFInfo" />             
            </map>
        </argument>
        <argument ref="exceptionHandler" />
    </bean>
```

whereas `myTemplate` is defined in `camelContext` which in turn is using `jsonRPCProcessor` as shown below:-

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
        useMDCLogging="true">
        <template id="myTemplate" />
        <route id="orchestrator-service-route">
            <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8888/orchestratorservice" />
            <process ref="jsonRPCProcessor" />
        </route>
        <route id="file-upload-service-route">
            <from
                uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8889/fileuploadservice?enableMultipartFilter=true" />
            <process ref="fileUploadProcessor" />
        </route>
...
</camelContext>
```

I have tried to set the `producer` in my custom Processor as mentioned in this [link](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-write-a-custom-processor-which-sends-multiple-messages.html). Can someone suggest me some other way of setting the `producer` in my custom `jsonRPCProcessor` so that it does not lead to any circular dependency?

Comment: Is there a reason you have divided them in three files? Why not one?

Comment: Yeah it was getting huge. Here so that it becomes easier to understand I added a very small part of it.

Comment: Well what I mean is, the complaint is of circular dependency so stuff in your configuration files are referring to each other. So that's what I mean, perhaps put all in one and make sure it works then divide them in three.

Comment: The same error was coming when I had everything in one file.

Comment: hard to see the problem, but I would probably put them all in one and comment out all the beans and just get the camelcontext started. Then add one bean at a time until you reach the error and then you know the suspect.

Comment: Is your jsonRPCProcessor class implements a Processor?

Comment: Yes it implements Processor

Comment: You seem to implement a lot of business logic using camel terms like Processor. Over time this will become even more complex and you will hit even more obscure errors. Try to use more plain java and your code will become a lot simpler. One way to do this is using the camel bean component. It allows to keep the business logic in a pojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get around this by removing  `myTemplate` from `jsonRPCProcesor` and `fileUploadProcessor`. Now my `jsonRPCProcessor` look something like below:-

```
<bean id="jsonRPCProcessor" class="com.j1.orchestratorservice.basecomponent.processor.JSONRPCProcessor">
    <argument>
        <map>           
            <entry key="Product.createProducts" value-ref="createProductsWFInfo" />
        </map>
    </argument>
    <argument ref="exceptionHandler" />
</bean>
```

Annotated the `ProducerTemplate`(in the base class) in my code with `@EndPointInject`. Something like below:-

```
@EndpointInject
protected ProducerTemplate myTemplate;
```